# Implementing search functionality and going to different pages in Next.js

Tags: next.js

I want to implement a search functionality from my project homepage. The search button is clicked after selecting the type of property and the location of the property. I am able to route to different property pages by using the useRouter hook. But I need to filter the data displayed based on the location also which needs to be passed to the property type component. Suppose I select property type as Land, and location as India, then it should take me to the Land property listings page with all lands in India displayed. How do I achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Pages structure

[image]

Comment: Do you already have API for this searching/filtering feature? And could you please provide more information about your pages structures? For example each property of the filter will be 1 page (`/land`, `/apartment`,...), or all of the filters just in the same page with different query params (`/search?type=land&location=India&...`)?

Comment: @haptn Thanks for the reply. The API fetches data for display and I would like to filter based on the location selected and the type of property which is a dropdown. I have edited my question to add the structure of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the solution using `useRouter` hook. Based on type of property selected, I am pushing the pathname and query parameter which is the selected location. Sample code snippet below:

```
...
     switch(selectedOption?.value) {
          case "Commercial property":
            //console.log("Render Commercial Property Search Form");
            router.push({pathname: "/property/commercial-space", query:{ keyword: selectedLoc}});
           
            break;
          case "Land & Plots":
          
            router.push({pathname: "/property/land", query:{ keyword: selectedLoc}});
          
            break;
          case "Warehouses & ColdStorage":
         
            router.push({pathname: "/property/warehouse", query:{ keyword: selectedLoc}});
          
            break;
            case "Factory & Industrial Building":
            
              router.push({pathname: "/property/industry", query:{ keyword: selectedLoc}});
              // Render Job Search Form component
              break;
          default:
        
            router.push({pathname: "/property/commercial-space", query:{ keyword: selectedLoc}});
            break;
        }
      
      }
...
```